# ORM tool for NodeJS MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, bookshelf.js, knex.js

Hi I am pretty new to NodeJS. I have worked with the MongoDB using the mongoose module. Now I am using MySQL for my current project and am trying to figure out the best options for ORM using MySQL. I have come across BookShelf.JS (with Knex.JS) node-orm2 and Squel.js
Has anyone used any of these or something else for a NodeJS MySQL/PostgreSQL/SQLite3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I love [Bookshelf](http://bookshelfjs.org). This question might be a little too subjective for SO, but I'll try to give a decent answer:

- Knex is a joy. It's a straightforward interface, reminiscent of Laravel's query builder.
- Bookshelf is a joy. It's a straightforward interface, reminiscent of Laravel's Eloquent ORM.

For most (not-too-big-and-probably-not-Node-appropriate) projects, Bookshelf/Knex will be all you need. They're easy to get running, and the codebases aren't *too* big if you decide that you need to work something out for yourself that isn't in the documentation.

Source: personal experience with a couple of the options. I've always found my way back to Bookshelf, though.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com), I use it and recommend. It supports all databases you described.

Squel.js isn't a ORM framework, and it's very useful for complex queries, I use it with SequelizeJS.